# Incorrect syntax near ','. error

Tags: asp.net, sql, syntax, connection

I am getting an SQL error when I try to do this:

```
    public static int GetOrderId(decimal totalprice, int userid)
    {
        string s = "SELECT * from orders where OrderUserId = " + userid + " and OrderTotalPrice = " + totalprice;
        cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        int temporderid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        return temporderid;
    }
```

As far I can see its because it gets OrderTotalPrice back, the format is incompatible. But I cant figure out how to get it in the compatible format.

Comment: You should use parameterised queries (though at least in this instance both values are at least guaranteed numeric)

Comment: What does the SQL command look like after it gets concatenated with the arguments? Basically the value of `s` before your command is executed. You also typically can't use ExecuteScalar with a `SELECT *` query. ExecuteScalar expects a single value to be returned and not a row of data.

Comment: so changing to a reader insteed could do the trick or ?

Comment: just changed it to: 

            string s = "SELECT * from orders where OrderUserId = " + userid + " and OrderTotalPrice = " + totalprice;
            cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int temporderid = (int)reader.GetSqlInt32(0);

            return temporderid;

but still get the same error, cuz of the formating

Comment: Couple of suggestions 1) use stored procs, you get bonuses such as performance and security.  2) if you only want to return 1 value do SELECT TOP 1 * instead of select *.  Im not sure if your error could be because you are selecting multiple records but trying to put them into an int variable which can only contain 1 value.

Comment: @KennetMadsen can you post the error text you are getting?

Comment: i have changed it to
`string s = "SELECT top 1 * from orders where OrderUserId = " + userid;
            cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int temporderid = (int)reader.GetSqlInt32(0);

            return temporderid;
`
Error massage: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

if i try the same select line in sql directly on the server with same parameters as the program tryes, i can get data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably formatting `totalprice` with a comma, like `3,14`, where SQL Server expects a dot, like `3.14`.

One way to fix that would be to specify InvariantCulture, which uses a dot:

```
var s = string.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    "SELECT * from orders where OrderUserId = {0} and OrderTotalPrice = {0:0.0}",
    42, 3.1415);
```

This formats the price as `3.1` on any machine.

By the way, it's much nicer to pass the variables as parameters:

```
var com = new SqlCommand();
com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
com.CommandText = "SELECT * from orders where OrderUserId = @userid " +
    "and OrderTotalPrice = @totalprice";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", 42);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalprice", 3.1415);
var temporderid = com.ExecuteScalar();
```

Then you don't have to worry about formats because you send the database a double, not a double formatted as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because totalprice gets converted to something like `12,35` when you concatenate the query.

Therefore, I'd suggest you use a parametrized query. E.g. like this:

```
var s = "SELECT * from orders " +
    " where OrderUserId = @userid and OrderTotalPrice = @totalprice";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userid", userid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("totalprice", totalprice);

int temporderid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```